# How to disable check lower and upper character Captcha on Playframework 1.24

Tags: playframework

How to change modules Captcha of playframe work to disable check character upper or lower?

Answer (score 0):

In Play framework 1.2.4 the captcha functionality isn't in a module, but is built-in in the framework core (in class [Images.Captcha](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2.4/play/libs/Images.Captcha.html)).

As you didn't share any code, it's impossible to  know how you've implemented your captcha validation so far, but let's assume you followed the [tutorials of Play framework documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/guide5). In that case, the actual validation (of whether the user-entered value matches the captcha value) doesn't take place inside the framework at all, but is left for you to implement.

If that is the case, all you need to do is use `equalsIgnoreCase` comparison instead of `equals`.